# sdl2 SDL_Quit() segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sdl

I encounter a segmentation fault when calling SDL_Quit() with the following code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH  = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int init(){
  return SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
}

void close(){
  SDL_Quit();
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if( init() < 0 ){
    SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }
  SDL_Delay(1000);
  close();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the gdb output:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe268) at src/main.c:18  
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.  
18    if( init() < 0 ){  
(gdb) print $eax  
$1 = 4196290  
(gdb) step  
init () at src/main.c:8  
8     return SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO);  
(gdb) print $eax  
$2 = 0  
(gdb) step  

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()  
(gdb)
```

However when I put everything in main like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0){
    SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

I do not get a segmentation fault.

Could you help me to understand the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first example you only init video.

Comment: @aggsol Thank you for answering ; I made the change but it didn't help.

Comment: Where is the segfault? What does the debugger say?

Comment: @Olaf I added the gdb ouput; it's weird because the segmentation appeared with SDL_Quit() and after adding "|SDL_INIT_AUDIO" the fault is now after the SDL_Init(..) call.

Comment: `SDL_Delay` is conspicuously absent from your second example. Or in other words, you shouldn't jump to the conclusion it's `SDL_Quit`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I now get the fault on SDL_Init(..VIDEO | ...AUDIO) on the second example...I don't get it -_-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odd segmentation fault with CC/GCC but not G++ (C/SDL2/Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304591/odd-segmentation-fault-with-cc-gcc-but-not-g-c-sdl2-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found the problem: I had to rename the functions init() and clsoe() because there was a conflict with already defined function.